# How to pull the full version of an app on Android?

Tags: android, apk, adb, apk-expansion-files, apktool

I'm having a hard time extracting APKs from my phone through ADB.

I tested my method with a random app: 2FAS

First, I use the command: `adb shell pm list package` to get the list of apps from my phone.
Then, I use the command: `adb shell pm path com.twofasapp` to get the path of the APK.
Finally, I use the command `adb pull /data/app/com.twofasapp/base.apk` to pull the APK.

But here is the problem, the size of the APK that gets pulled from my phone it's a lot smaller than the one posted on APK Mirror even though is the same version of the app.
The one I pulled from my phone is 14.50 MB while the one from APK Mirror is 55.77 MB.

It looks like the adb pull command it's not pulling the full version. Why is that?

How can I pull the full APK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, you install 56 MB APK and after pulling it out of the phone it is "shrunk" to 14.5 MB? Or is the app you're pulling installed from another source?

Comment: I installed the app from the Play Store but when I pull it, it's just 14.5 MB.

Comment: When I install the APK from another source (APK Mirror) and then pull it, it pulls the full (bigger) version just fine. So the Play Store version of the app is smaller. When I install the Play Store version and pull the APK and then I use that APK to try to install it on another device, it doesn't open

Comment: Well, Play Store enforces [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) format which "generate and serve optimized APKs for each device configuration" so that's why you're getting smaller APKs and same reason why it won't open on another device (unless it has identical configuration).

Comment: Any solution for this? Like, is there any way to pull the full version and not the optimized version?

Comment: Logically, how would you get full apk out of device when it's never there?

Comment: I meant, is there a way to pull the full version out of the Play Store? Is there any device brand that needs the full version and therefore the full version needs to be downloaded from the Play Store?

Comment: How to scrape APK out of the play store is a completely different (and legally gray) question.

Comment: APK app bundles are supported since Android 5. For newer apps AFAIK Google enforces to use app bundles so you can not get an all-in-one APK file for those apps as it does not exist.

Comment: The only "non-optimized version" you can get is the full bunch of APK files as it is provided by sites like https://apkmirror.com https://apkpure.com and so on. What you download there is a ZIP containing all available app bundles (those site use a large set of different virtual devices to download all of them). If you are concerned of the security of those APK files you can verify the APK signature (the certificate SHA-256 digest) of your own APK file and compare it with the downloaded one https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218161/2241